# How to keep spinner moving till components are getting rendered in <aura:iteration>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I am rendering components over a loop and it is taking time, so want to keep spinner moving till the iteration/component rendering is over. How to achieve this?
aura:waiting and aura:doneWaiting work only for server calls

> code:

```
            <aura:iteration aura:id="iterationID" var="var1" items="{!v.List1}">
            <tr>
                <aura:iteration var="var2" items="{!v.List2}">
                    <td >
                        <div class="slds-truncate">
                            <c:componentRendered attr1={"!var1"} attr2={"!var2"}/>
                        </div> 
                    </td>
                </aura:iteration>
            </tr>
        </aura:iteration>
```

> Update:

Can we somehow use "[loaded](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_aura_iteration.htm)" attribute of  to indicate that it has been loaded, and if its TRUE, hide the spinner?? Can't find how to use this attribute in markup!

Comment: I think you're looking for [aura:doneRendering](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_aura_doneRendering.htm)?

Comment: tried that as well, it says in docs that: "Indicates that the initial rendering of the root application or root component has completed."

So in my case, it seems that it doesn't wait for components in iteration to be rendered and stops spinning after half rotation. 

However, it still is visible on screen, but just static...it's not rotating